# Search for a string and copy cells two rows down

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large workbook with many sheets - I need to loop through each sheet and copy a specific row of data over to a master sheet.  The code I have for this part works fine - the data I want to copy over to the master sheet will always be found in row 17.  However, the location (column) in row 17 where I want to start copying my data from varies.  I need to search the headers row (row 15) for the string "Expenses", and after locating this cell move down two rows to row 17 and copy the rest of that row of data starting from the column where the word "Expenses" is found.  Currently, my code is just copying the entire row of data.  Can anyone help me modify this code to search for a string and then use that location to copy the data?

```
Sub MasterSheet()

Dim Sht As Worksheet

Sheets("Master").Select
Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sht.Name <> "Master" Then
        Sht.Select
        Range("A:A").Insert
        Range("A17").Formula = "=Mid(Cell(""filename"",B1),Find(""]"",Cell(""filename""))+1,255)"
        Range("A17").Copy
        Range("A17").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Range("A17:T17").Copy
        Sheets("Master").Select
        Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sht.Select
        Range("A:A").Delete
    Else
End If

Next Sht
Sheets("Master").Select
Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearFormats
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MasterSheet()

    Dim Sht As Worksheet, f As Range, shtM As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set shtM = wb.Sheets("Master")
    shtM.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If Sht.Name <> shtM.Name Then

            'find the header
            Set f = Sht.Rows(15).Find("Expenses", , xlValues, xlWhole)

            'if the header was found...
            If Not f Is Nothing Then

                With shtM.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

                    .Value = Sht.Name 'sheet name in ColA
                    'copy the values two rows down from f
                    'change the 100 to suit
                    .Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 100).Value = _
                              f.Offset(2, 0).Resize(1, 100).Value
                End With
            End If

        End If 'checking this sheet

    Next Sht

    shtM.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearFormats
    shtM.Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```